# Prove that the Lipschitz constant cannot be less than $1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I was asked to study the following map: let $I=[0,1]$ and let $f(s)=\log(1+s^2)$ for any $s\in\mathbb R$. For every $u\in L^1(I,\mathbb R)$ we set $$(F(u))(x)=\int_0^xf(u(t))\mathrm d t.$$

First of all I had shown that $F$ maps $L^1(I,\mathbb R)$ into itself. Then the second point was to show that $F$ is Lipschitz continuous from $L^1(I,\mathbb R)$ into itself with Lipschitz constant less than or equal than $1$, and I've done that.

Finally the problem asked to show that the Lipschitz constant couldn't be less than $1$. My first approach was to use the Caccioppoli Banach lemma to derive a sort of a contradiction. However if you study the integral equation $$\begin{cases}u(x)=\int_0^x\log(1+u(t)^2)\mathrm d t\\ u(0)=0,\end{cases}$$ then by unicity of the solution one sees that $u\equiv 0$ is the only fixed point... if I am not mistaken.

Then i tried to find a sequence of function $u_\lambda\in L^1(I,\mathbb R)$, with $\lambda<1$ such that, $\|Fu_\lambda\|_{L^1}>\lambda\|u_\lambda\|_{L^1}$, but i had no success.

Can anybody help me please? thank you...

EDIT: As I have written in the comment after DId answer, I don't think that his method matches my idea of proceeding in the exercise.. as it is written, it sounds troublesome to me.. Can anyone help me in finishing the problem?

Ps: sorry for accepting the answer, but as I wrote in the comment, I rushed in checking the detail because that kind of functions were also my first candidate to solve the exercise. However, let me again thank Did for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $u_{a,b}=a\mathbf 1_{(0,b)}$ with $0\lt b\lt 1\leqslant a$, and $\ell(a)=\log(1+a^2)$.

Then $\|u_{a,b}-u_{1,b}\|_1=(a-1)b$ and $F(u_{a,b})(x)=\ell(a)\min\{x,b\}$  hence 
$$
\|F(u_{a,b})-F(u_{1,b})\|_1=(\ell(a)-\ell(1))\int_0^1\min\{x,b\}\mathrm dx=(\ell(a)-\ell(1))b(1-\tfrac12b).
$$
Since $\ell'(1)=1$, $\|F(u_{a,b})-F(u_{1,b})\|_1\sim (a-1)b=\|u_{a,b}-u_{1,b}\|_1$ when $a\to1^+$ and $b\to0$. In particular, no inequality $\|F(u)-F(v)\|_1\leqslant c\|u-v\|_1$ may hold for every integrable functions $u$ and $v$, if $c\lt1$.

On the other hand, $\ell$ is $1$-Lipschitz hence, for every $x$ in $(0,1)$,
$$
|F(u)(x)-F(v)(x)|\leqslant\int_0^1|\ell(u)-\ell(v)|\leqslant\int_0^1|u-v|=\|u-v\|_1.
$$
This shows that $F$ is $1$-Lipschitz but not $c$-Lipschitz for any $c\lt1$.

Comment: @Did... I accepted your answer because I had your same thought and thus I believed it was correct.. incidentally today I've remade the calculations... It turned out that with your suggestions $\lim_{a,b\to 0}\|Fu\|_1=\lim_{a,b\to 0}\log(1+a^2)b(1-\frac b2)=a^2b$, while $\|u\|_1=ab$ therefore the limit of the quotient of the norm goes to $0$ in your statement.. This confuses me.. Where am I wrong? thank you very much... PS: Maybe the approach $\|Fu\lambda\|_1>\lambda\|u_\lambda\|_1$ is just wrong?

Comment: @Did.. Sorry to do that but I'm unchecking your answer temporarily but i will recheck as soon as somebody convinces me of its validity.. sorry again..

Comment: Please do not feel sorry, my previous hint was misleading hence I am the one who should apologize. See revised version.